# Capitalize first letter of each line using PHP

Tags: php, capitalize

I'd like if there was a way to capitalize the first letter of each line using PHP.

```
<?php 
$text="namjaga da geureochi mwo narago dareugetni
cheoeumen da akkyeojwodo naragabeorigo maneun
namjaga da geureochi mwo narago teukbyeolhalkka
ni mameul da gajyeodo naragabeorigo maneun
namjaga da geureochi mwo"
?>

<p>
<?php echo $text; ?>
</p>
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You tried something like searching PHP manual OR stackoverflow ?

Comment: I did many times, but everything was about capitalizing the first letter of each word or of a string. Yet, I had not thought about David's answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$textParts = explode("\n", $text);
foreach ($textParts as $key => $value) {
   $textParts[$key] = ucfirst($value);
}

$text = implode("\n", $textParts);
```